# How to change the scaling label of date value from numeric format to date format in r when plotting?

Tags: r

I used the following code to plot a time series data, but get numeric output in x-axis as '18250'. Does anybody know how to make the x-axis display in date format like '2019-12-01'?

```
b <- plot(ts(cum_confirm, start = as.Date('2019-12-01'), frequency = 1))
```

Output plot:

[image: Output Plot]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `xts` library. You did not share any data so I generated a sample dataset.

```
dm <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(14914, 14915, 14916, 14917, 
14918, 14919, 14920, 14921, 14922, 14923, 14924, 14925), class = "Date"), 
    Visits = c(696537L, 718748L, 799355L, 805800L, 701262L, 531579L, 
    690068L, 756947L, 718757L, 701768L, 820113L, 645259L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
dm

#         Date Visits
#1  2010-11-01 696537
#2  2010-11-02 718748
#3  2010-11-03 799355
#4  2010-11-04 805800
#5  2010-11-05 701262
#6  2010-11-06 531579
#7  2010-11-07 690068
#8  2010-11-08 756947
#9  2010-11-09 718757
#10 2010-11-10 701768
#11 2010-11-11 820113
#12 2010-11-12 645259
```

Now using `xts` library dates are maintained.

```
plot(xts::xts(dm[-1], dm[[1]]), main = 'Plot')
```

[image]